# Restore the windows bootloader without the CD

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bootloader

I will be giving my desktop to my brother soon. He is a gamer, so he has no need for a dual-boot Linux install. I can easily remove the Linux partitions and re size the Windows partition, but this will break GRUB, my current boot loader. I would simply use the Windows 7 CD, but I have misplaced it. How can I make Windows boot without the install media?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) can replace grub with bcd (and chainloads grub). You can then delete the partitions as needed. I've also heard good things about [visual bcd editor](http://www.boyans.net/) on SU chat, but i've not used it myself.

As a backup, you can also create a system recovery disk in the windows backup and restore menu. This would be a good time to back up your windows system in case something goes wrong as well! You can use the system recovery disk to fix your bootloader. [Microsoft has full instructions with a video here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc)

Comment: Thanks! The Windows rescue CD worked like a charm. For reference, here are the commands I used at the command prompt once the CD was booted:

BootRec.exe /FixBoot BootRec.exe /FixMbr

Comment: When using the Windows rescue CD, make sure that your Windows hard disk is your first boot option in the bios before doing this (just temporarily boot from the cd, don't change the boot order). I got "missing bootmgr" because of that. Running the same commands again with Windows as first boot device fixed it.